# MYSQL - Function LENGHT does not exists

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde.

Preciso encontrar uma forma de separar os RGs dos CPFs de um banco com + de 10k de registros.

Minha solução para conseguir visualiza-los de forma separada para serem tratados depois foi:

SELECT nome, doc FROM pessoas
WHERE LEN(doc) <= 9 ( para RGs )

e

SELECT nome, doc FROM pessoas
WHERE LEN(doc) >= 9 ( para CPF )

Contudo, o MySQL me retorna um erro dizendo que a função LEN não existe, tentei também com CHAR_LENGTH e algumas outras formas que encontrei pesquisando, mas sem nenhum sucesso até agora.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: À parte do propósito da pergunta, creio que haja um erro de lógica aí. Nos dois casos, RG e CPF, o `LEN(doc)` pode ser igual a `9`? E não seria `LENGTH` em vez de `LEN`?

Comment: `LENGHT` não existe mesmo, o que existe é `LENGTH`

Comment: Basicamente o meu problema era que recebi um banco extremamente desorganizado, onde CPF e RG estavam na mesma column, e eu precisava tentar filtrar eles de alguma forma... A primeira idéia q tive foi fazer um select, onde eu conseguisse primeiro pegar todos os CPFs ( 11 digítos ) e extrair eles, e depois fazer o mesmo com o restante para pegar os RGs, assim eu importaria eles separadamente p uma nova table c colunas específicas p cada doc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

no MySQL a função que retorna a quantidade de caracteres se chama LENGTH.

Com isso, o correto seria:

SELECT nome, doc FROM pessoas WHERE LENGTH (doc) <= 9; --( para RGs )

e

SELECT nome, doc FROM pessoas WHERE LENGTH (doc) >= 9; --( para CPF )

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo, hoje à tarde eu tentei de alguma forma escrevendo LENGTH também mas devo ter feito algo errado na sintaxe sem perceber, e acabei encontrando a sintaxe com LEN tentei, e sem sucesso também.